# banquo/phantom nodejs error - Cannot read property 'createPage' of undefined

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

im trying to run https://github.com/ajam/banquo-server and receiving and error

> Cannot read property 'createPage' of undefined

```
Express server listening on port 3000
Requesting http://america.aljazeera.com
/root/banquo-server/node_modules/banquo/src/banquo.js:36
    ph.createPage(openPage);
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPage' of undefined
    at createPage (/root/banquo-server/node_modules/banquo/src/banquo.js:36:7)
    at /root/banquo-server/node_modules/node-phantom/node-phantom.js:65:6
    at null._onTimeout (/root/banquo-server/node_modules/node-phantom/node-phantom.js:43:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #7
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
```

I have checked and an error is being returned from node-phantom.js:36 but does not specify what.

any ideas?

regards

Comment: Perhaps this should be an issue on GitHub. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: not a bug as this works on my local mac, not on external server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue and fixed it adding the **phantomjs** binary to [PATH](https://superuser.com/q/284342/412023).

You can test if it is already set running the command:

```
$ phantomjs
```

The following error means that it isn't:

> 'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

As you said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024163/banquo-phantom-nodejs-error-cannot-read-property-createpage-of-undefined#comment50073037_31024163):

> not a bug as this works on my local mac, not on external server

So, that's not a problem with your code. That's a problem with your environment so I guess that you also missed to set the PATH variable.